# simpest way to get audio/video data from directshow

Tags: c++, windows, directshow

I compiled the DirectShow sample player (from the Windows SDK's "Samples\multimedia\directshow\players\dshowplayer" folder).

Everything works well but it renders directly to the screen and the audio goes directly to directsound.  I need to be able to grab the data and write out images to BMPs and write out the audio to .wav.

Am I using the wrong sample as a starting point?  If not, what is the easiest way to modify the sample so I can get access to the video and audio data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can insert a SampleGrabber filter before the renderer, and use the [ISampleGrabberCB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd376985%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) Interface to access the data. You can still render the video to the screen, and output the audio. If you don't want that, use a NullRenderer instead. See also [this example on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/directx/saveimagefromstreamingurl.aspx).